# Trying to reference an element and influence another element using data attribute

Tags: jquery

I have multiple input fields with a variable data attribute and each input field has a corresponding button. I am trying to check and see if there is a value in each of the input fields. If there is, the color of the corresponding button changes. But I am having trouble referencing using data attributes. Here is what I have..

HTML:

```
 <td>
   <textarea data-id="<%= textID %>"></textarea>
 </td>

 <td>
   <input type="button" data-id="<%= textID %>"/>
 </td>
```

Where TextID is a variable. Reason I want to use data-id is because there are a lot of rows in the table and this is the cleanest way to do it.

jQuery:

```
 var text = $.trim($('textarea[data-id="' + textID + '"')).val(),
     button = $('input[type=button][data-id="' + textID + '"]');

 if (text.length !== 0) {
     $(button).css('background-color','white');
     }
```

This is not working, I have a gut feeling I'm referencing it wrongly or there is a problem with syntax. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're missing a closing bracket in your textarea selector:

```
$('textarea[data-id="' + textID + '"]')
                                 // ^
```

Second, you are `trim()`ing the jquery object, not the value:

```
$.trim($('textarea[data-id="' + textID + '"]') .val())
                             // move paren    ^------^
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 var text = $.trim($('textarea[data-id="' + textID + '"')).val(),
     button = $('input[type=button][data-id="' + textID + '"]');

 if (text.length !== 0) {
     $(button).css('background-color','white');
     }
```

You have an error on the first line, you are missing the closing ], it should be

```
var text = $.trim($('textarea[data-id="' + textID + '"]').val())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery:

```
var text = $.trim($('textarea[data-id="' + textID + '"]').val()),
    button = $('input[type=button][data-id="' + textID + '"]');

if (text.length !== 0) {
    $(button).css('background-color','white');
}
```